# Array in Array Handling in PosgresQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have extracted array from JsonB data-type of PostgresQL 10.5 based on below query. which gives array data but as text (see in column header).

[image: Snapshot of Parent table]

Parent Data-Table having JSONB Column

Code extracting array-text from JSONB column

```
SELECT "Path" -> 'points' ->> 'coordinates' AS ca from public."Route"
```

[image: Snapshot after extractions of Coordinate Array]

referring to below snapshot which gives text column in output

I require to handle this table in such a way that i can call x & y coordinates (of array `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...]`) thru SQL

Comment: Your first output is **not** "an array" - it's a JSON value with key/value pairs. And you should post [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) for sample data, not screen shots that would make things a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Sticky bit for guidance.... I got full solution thru [Blog](http://cwestblog.com/2012/06/14/postgresql-convert-string-to-table/)

```
SELECT array_agg(t) 
FROM ( 
       SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UNNEST(a), '[', ''), ']', ''),' ','')::decimal AS t, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS r 
       FROM ( 
              SELECT STRING_TO_ARRAY(jsonb_array_elements_text("Path"->'points'->'coordinates'), ',') a 
              FROM "Route" 
            ) t 
      ) t 
Group by r 
order by r;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery in which the JSON array is turned to set with `jsonb_array_elements_text()` and then aggregated to an array with `array_agg()` and casted along the way.

```
SELECT (SELECT array_agg(jae.e::decimal)
               FROM jsonb_array_elements_text("Path"->'points'->'coordinates') jae(e)) points
FROM "Route";
```

Comment: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "[73.21876, 22.355220000000003]"
SQL state: 22P02

Comment: data structure is decimal into array into array 
[[decimal,decimal],[decimal,decimal],...]

Comment: replacing **decimal** with **text** gives me output array-as-string but I reuire array-of-decimals `SELECT (SELECT array_agg(jae.e::text)
               FROM jsonb_array_elements_text("Path"->'points'->'coordinates') jae(e)) points
FROM "Route";`

Comment: Solution : [source](http://cwestblog.com/2012/06/14/postgresql-convert-string-to-table/)
`SELECT array_agg(t)
    FROM (
      SELECT
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UNNEST(a), '[', ''), ']', ''),' ','')::decimal AS t,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS r
      FROM (
        SELECT STRING_TO_ARRAY(jsonb_array_elements_text("Path"->'points'->'coordinates'), ',') a FROM "Route"
      ) t
    ) t
Group by r
order by r;`